# Can users modify data using Access (front-end) interface while the data is located on a back-end SQLServer ? If so how?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Here is part of the code where I tried to change dbOpenForwardOnly to dbOpenDynaset

Set select_delay = db.OpenRecordset("Select delay from MapOnDemand where No_Map = " & CInt(no), _
        dbOpenForwardOnly)

And it did not work. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, they can. Why not link the tables? Have you checked permissions? You will also need to look at dbSeeChanges. `db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code, absolutely.  We do this all the time, with tables that are quite large.

First of all, you should link your tables in Linked Table Manager.  You can also link them in code, but the code I have used is a bit unwieldly.  So, unless it's a generic database that will only serve as a shell, I would suggest linking the tables using the Linked Table Manager.

Then, using your code from your question, you would do something like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim sSQL as String

Set db = CurrentDB
Set sSQL = "Select delay from MapOnDemand where No_Map = " & CInt(no) & "") 
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

You can also set sSQL equal to an Update query and it will work fine.

Also, don't forget that if No_Map is a String, it will need to be surrounded by single quotes, so you would replace that line with:

```
Set sSQL = "Select delay from MapOnDemand where No_Map = '" & CInt(no) & "'")
```

Comment: Why not dbFailOnError?

Comment: You can use dbFailOnError, or you can trap the error.  I prefer to trap the error so my handlers are more effective and descriptive.  Both are acceptable, though.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I very much doubt that you will get a database error without dbFailOnError. Database errors and code errors are two quite separate things. I generally use two error traps, as recommended by MS.